# Como editar un archivo.txt o cualquier formato con python

Tags: python-3.x

Nose como editar un archivo con python
Osea imaginen
Este es mi archivo:
test.txt
Contenido del archivo:
Incluye toda la informacion que
algiien necesitaría para responder
Tu pregunta

Obviamente "algiien" este mal se puede borrar esa palabra y añadir una nueva el correcto "alguien" en el mismo lugar es posible eso y como aserlo

Comment: Podés añadir contenido al txt, pero no eliminar (si querés eliminar contenido del txt inevitablemente tendrás que crear uno nuevo). Si queres una respuesta más detallada, te recomiendo que añadas a tu pregunta lo que intentaste (en forma de [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) o una lista de algunos de los links que visitaste. Es importante demostrar que sos parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero abrimos el archivo y lo leemos

```
#esto abre el archivo y gurda todo en archivo
with open('test.txt') as archivo:
    #aqui leemos el archivo y lo asignamos a contenido
    contenido = archivo.read()
```

Cabe resaltar que con with open abre el archivo y lo cierra automáticamente, te recomiendo leer este tutorial para saber mas sobre esto

https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/python-abre-archivo-como-leer-un-archivo-de-texto-linea-por-linea/

Después buscamos la palabra y la reemplazamos en nuestra variable

```
#reemplazamos la palabra
contenido_correjido = contenido.replace('algiien', 'alguien')
```

Y al final solo volvemos a sobrescribir el archivo esto borrara todo el contenido y escribirá el contenido nuevo

```
#volvemos abrir el archivo
with open('test.txt', 'w') as archivo:
    #escribimos en el
    archivo.write(contenido_correjido)
```

Y eso seria todo ya te queda de tarea ver las excepciones en caso de que no exista el archivo,porque marca error si el archivo no existe. Saludos :)

Comment: Bueno no era lo que buscaba pero me diste una alternativa Muchas gracias ya conocia el tema solo queria saber si era posible aser eso broo perdon si les moleste y tu respuesta si me ayudo

Comment: Como te dije en mi comentario, no es posible borrar contenido del archivo sin sobreescribirlo como lo muestra esta respuesta (al menos eso dicen en el sitio en inglés). Pero si podés agregar contenido. No molestaste a nadie, si tu pregunta queda cerrada y sin respuestas por que no cumple los lineamientos del sitio no es nuestro problema. Pero estaría bueno tanto para vos como para el sitio que hubieses agregado algo que demuestre que sos parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda.